# If $(\sqrt{x^2-5x+6} + \sqrt{x^2-5x+4})^{x/2} + (\sqrt{x^2-5x+6} - \sqrt{x^2-5x+4})^{x/2}=2^{\frac{x+4}{4}}$, find $x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

The main question is :
If $(\sqrt{x^2-5x+6} + \sqrt{x^2-5x+4})^{x/2} + (\sqrt{x^2-5x+6} - \sqrt{x^2-5x+4})^{x/2}=2^{\frac{x+4}{4}}$, 
find $x$.

My method :
I first began by substituting $x^2-5x+5$ as $t$.
This makes my equation become :
$$(\sqrt{t+1} + \sqrt{t-1})^{x/2} + (\sqrt{t+1} - \sqrt{t-1})^{x/2}=2^{\frac{x+4}{4}}$$.
I tried squaring but it got even more complicated.
Please help me.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you delete your last question, ten minutes ago? I was too busy writing down an answer (perhaps I was wrong, though) and I could not follow the comments (nor could I post my answer, in the end). Avoid doing it, please.

Comment: What did you edit @DeepSea?

Comment: You have both $+$ in the left side which is wrong, I changed the second sign to $-$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli, I'll ask that one again. I framed it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $A = \left(\sqrt{t+1} + \sqrt{t-1}\right)^{\frac{x}{2}}, B = \left(\sqrt{t+1}-\sqrt{t-1}\right)^{\frac{x}{2}}$, then apply the AM-GM inequality: $A+B \ge 2\sqrt{AB}$ and note that $AB = 2^{\frac{x}{2}}$. Thus the left side $\ge $ the right side, and we have equality so $A = B \implies t = 1 \implies x^2-5x+5 = 1 \implies (x-1)(x-4) = 0 \implies x = 1,4$.

Comment: How do I apply AM GM inequality here? Please help me.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment?

Comment: Alright I got it. Thanks a bunch guys.